# Ruby on Rails -Reading xls file using Spreadsheet RubyGem

Tags: ruby

I am using the following code to read an excel file using the `Spreadsheet` gem.

```
require 'spreadsheet'
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'    

book = Spreadsheet.open('C:\Users\Lev Berlin\Documents\Personal\Projects\FactsRus\Nutritional Analysis Models\Data for Rails model import.xls')
sheet1 = book.worksheet('Sheet1')
```

But the file is not being read properly.

When I uncomment `require 'parseexel'` line in another file then files are processed properly.

Please help me; what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not reading properly"? Do you get an error message; is the data you get in your program not matching what's in the file; is there a data conversion problem...?

Comment: No, i am not getting any error. But it return spreadsheet object instead of return row value.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the worksheet loaded (that's what you did with "sheet1 = ...), you need to read the rows from that sheet. You do this like so:

```
sheet1.each do |row|
    # do something interesting with a row
  end
```

Check out http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/files/GUIDE_txt.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using like below..

```
require 'spreadsheet'


@workbook = Spreadsheet.open(MyFile.first.attachment.to_file)

@worksheet = @workbook.worksheet(0)

0.upto @worksheet.last_row_index do |index|


  row = @worksheet.row(index)

  @contact = Contact.new
  #row[0] is the first cell in the current row, row[1] is the second cell, etc...
  @contact.first_name = row[0]



 @contact.last_name = row[1]

  @contact.save

end
```